# converting epoch time to time zone in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe with following epoch time as columns in `pandas`

```
0    1602206700206666
1    1602206700206668
2    1602206700206670
3    1602206700206672
4    1602206700206674
```

I am trying to convert this to datetime. The following is the code I used:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit="ns", utc=True)
```

However, I get a strange output of

```
0   1970-01-19 13:03:26.700206666+00:00
1   1970-01-19 13:03:26.700206668+00:00
2   1970-01-19 13:03:26.700206670+00:00
3   1970-01-19 13:03:26.700206672+00:00
4   1970-01-19 13:03:26.700206674+00:00
```

which is strange because the date should not be 1970-01 but should be 2020-10. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

They are unix timestamp, which is in milliseconds since epoch. Pandas uses nanosecond on integers. So try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time']*1000)
```

Output:

```
0   2020-10-09 01:25:00.206666
1   2020-10-09 01:25:00.206668
2   2020-10-09 01:25:00.206670
3   2020-10-09 01:25:00.206672
4   2020-10-09 01:25:00.206674
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your time is in microseconds, so use `us` instead of `ns`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit="us", utc=True)

print (df)

                              time
0 2020-10-09 01:25:00.206666+00:00
1 2020-10-09 01:25:00.206668+00:00
2 2020-10-09 01:25:00.206670+00:00
3 2020-10-09 01:25:00.206672+00:00
4 2020-10-09 01:25:00.206674+00:00
```